# Update DGV from other form

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to update a Data Grid View (DGV) from one form to another form. The initial form is called 'stock' in which we find a combobox with products and a DGV which includes products with the correspondent amounts (meaning, 2 columns)

I give the option to add a new product with a button in "stock" form. The code is:

```
 Private Sub btnProducto_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnProducto.Click
    Dim productos As New Productos(Me)
    productos.Show()
End Sub
```

In one hand, in the "products" form, is just a textbox for the name of the new product with a button to save in the DB. In addition, I update DGV of the "stock" form

```
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
End Sub

Public Sub New(stock As stock)
    Me.New()
    _stock = stock
End Sub

Private Sub btnProducto_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnProducto.Click
    Dim stock As New stock
    oBaseDatos = New CLSoledb("bd.accdb")
    oBaseDatos.Insertar_Servicio(txtProducto.Text, 2)

    _stock.rellenarProductosDGV()
    Me.Close()

End Sub
```

In the "stock" form, specifically in the load, I call to the method "rellenarProductosDGV"() and with no problems the method adds the information in the DGV. Adding the product from the "products" form and using:

```
_stock.rellenarProductosDGV()
```

It just filled the DGV if I put the messagebox.show("test"). If I put off the messagebox, the DGV of "stock" form don't update, the same products remain when they are reloaded the "stock" load. This is the original method:

```
Public Sub rellenarProductosDGV()
    MessageBox.Show("test")
    oBaseDatos = New CLSoledb("autovag.accdb")
    DSProductos = New DataSet
    dgvStock.Rows.Clear()
    Dim SentenciaSQL As String = "select nombre,cantidad from ser_Pro where tipo=2"
    DSProductos = oBaseDatos.AccionSelect(SentenciaSQL)

    For f = 0 To DSProductos.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
        dgvStock.Rows.Add()
        For c = 0 To 1
            dgvStock.Item(c, f).Value = DSProductos.Tables(0).Rows(f).Item(c)
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

What I understand is that it could be any problem related with the execution time, because when the program stops with the messagebox it can complete the tasks, on the contrary the DGV don't update regardless of the products that are added from the "products" form to the DB. Any recommendation?

Comment: You should start by not populating the grid manually but rather simply binding the `DataTable` to it. Secondly, you should not save data to the database from the second form and then try to get it back again in the first form.  The second form should simply gather the data and pass it back to the first form.  The first form then adds a new row to the `DataTable`, which will cause it to show up in the grid.  The first form then saves all the changes from the `DataTable` back to the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a new row you do do either .add or .insert, but please add data along with it.

Like this:

```
DGV.Rows.Add(value1,value2,...,n) 'each value will then be in one column
```

You could also work with DataTable because it's quicker, for example making 10.000 rows directly to DGV takes ~1500ms while adding them to DataTable and binding it to DGV takes ~35ms

But if there's little data, there's little to no difference.